Why is atoi() working as expected here, but when I use atol(), it returns 0 and modifies the input string to be empty ("")?
Edit: I am realizing that staging ground comment history is no longer visible when a post goes public: so I'll clarify a few points here. This function works fine when called directly from main(), but not from its current location on the call stack. I have included the screenshots because I am not able to use printf() (or similar functions) in my current environment; I believe this is due my heap being underallocated, but that's besides the point. Since I can't use print statements, I place breakpoints at NOP instructions and view the variable contents in the debugger, hence the screenshots.
A few commenters in the staging ground pointed out that I am likely running out of stack space at this particular atol() call, which is why the function is returning 0, and the original string is being modified. My question is now, what can I do to achieve the same functionality as atol(), without exceeding the stack range?

Original:
I've never created a post on this site before, so please let me know if I'm asking my question incorrectly. I have some code here that accepts an ASCII input string (ex. "10000"), converts it to an integer, and passes it along to a different section of the code. When I use atoi(), the function works as expected, and overflows at an input of "32768". However, when I try to use atol(), no matter what the input string is, the function will return 0. In addition, the input string (value), will become empty (ex. "" instead of "10000"). Here is my code:
void Cmd_LoadRelPos(char *value)
{
    int32 test;
    test = atol(value);
    CY_NOP;
}

The problem here is that I must be able to convert to 32 bit integers, and 32768 is simply too low of an upper limit for my needs. Does anyone have any advice?
If it helps, this code runs on a PSoC3 (8051 based) system, and I am using Keil for my compiler. I'll attach of what I'm seeing in the debugger as well.
 and 
 and 

Please don't post images of text. Least of all code or input/output. Copy-paste text as text into your questions. Also please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and hard-code possible input to make testing and debugging easier.

As for your problem, on some small and simple systems there might not be a native 32-bit type, and you either need to link with certain libraries to add 32-bit functionality, or you have to work around it some other way (like doing the parsing of the input string yourself, which is quite simple and trivial).

Did you try long instead of int32?

@JoopEggen yes, and the behavior is the same as int32 is defined by Cypress as a signed long, but I've revised my post with some more info that I just realized did not make it past the staging ground

Since it is 8051, it could be a stack overflow. Or atol being too large a function to even fit inside your microcontroller. Or simply some archaic crap compiler being full of bugs. Is it too late to port to a microcontroller from this millennium?

Although if optimizations are enabled the compiler is free to ignore any or all of the function body of that function...  Look at the disassembly to see if the compiler actually bothered to generate the code you assume it will generate. What happens if you actually return an int32_t from the function?

"I believe this is due my heap being underallocated" Eh? It's an 8051. It barely has RAM, there's no room for a heap nor would it make the slightest sense to allocate one.

The atol() function you are using does not follow the rules dictated by the C Standard (*)
Use this one instead (which also does not follow the C Standard rules)
/*
** my_atol does not deal with negative numbers or leading whitespace
** if `data` represents a larger value than LONG_MAX the behaviour is undefined
*/
long my_atol(const char *data) {
    long r = 0;
    while (('0' <= *data) && (*data <= '9')) {
        r *= 10;
        r += *data++ - '0';
    }
    return r;
}

(*) https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.2

"Use this one instead" and define it before Cmd_LoadRelPos().

This gives me several syntax errors (parameter name omitted, expected expression x2, expression is not assignable), which likely result from the fact that I am forced into using C89 instead of a more modern standard.

Those errors are NOT related to the code I presented which, BTW, is very much valid C89.
